# Videos - should I include them in my app?

Tags: video, size

Thanks to you, I got my working hours calculator on the App Store. :) Now for my next one - I want to make an app that includes video of my series of tutorials. However, I want to know whether it's good form to include the videos directly inside the app or not? If I do, the app size would be something in the region of 80mb as it would include up to 30 minutes of tutorials. Should I be bothered about the size?

Thanks!

EDIT: The app in question would be a tutorial application around voice acting. I have made videos online and wish to include them on an app so people could have a direct video of each of the lessons. Not only that, I would include text tips in a different view. I would include the first 6 episodes in the app so people can view all the lessons in one go and get started.

Comment: Every question is a new question in its own right, you need to describe your application before this question is answerable.

Comment: Edited the question - hopefully this should help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for keeping the videos separate, if you wanted to update them it'd be much easier.  The downside would be people distributing them separately if that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, keep them separate if you can, but also allow users to download them in app for offline use.  As an iPod Touch user, I can attest to the fact that without that, apps are often useless.